# how does a zookeeper cluster of 3 stay active when 1 node is down?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, paxos

the documentation [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/FAQ#A7) says that:

> A 3 server ensemble allows for a single server to fail and the service will still be available.

However, for a quorum to be established, there need to be `ceil(n/2)+1` nodes

In the case of 3 nodes, that is:
`ceil(3/2)+1 = ceil(1.5)+1 = 3`

So if 1 node is down, the quorum should not be established and zookeeper should go down.

Is the above documentation wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quorum is 2 in a three node cluster as that is a majority. Any two majorities in space or time must overlap; so cannot be unaware of actions in any other majority as at least one node is in both majorities. That's a fundermental property used by the Paxos algorithm (note Zookeeper uses ZAB not Paxos my point is that safety in a consensus algorithm uses majorities). So your calculation should be `floor(N/2)+1` which gives a quorum of 2 in a 3 node cluster, 3 in a 5 node cluster, 4 in a 7 node cluster, etc.

Comment: Fundamentally correct answer, but ZooKeeper does not use Paxos. It uses the ZooKeeper Atomic Broadcast protocol (ZAB) which is more similar to Raft than Paxos. The leader is the single node that's always in the majority.

Comment: Yes I am aware as I recently stated on a comment to someone else's question. I will edit the answer to be clear that it's simply required for any safe algorithm eg Paxos.